# Is there a way to give a div width and height from a different object (share parameters)

Tags: html, parameters, height, width

I wish to know if it's possible to give a  dimension properties from an img or any other object. I tried giving the img a name through name="..." and then entering div width="name" height="name" though that obviously didn't work.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to know? You want to give an element another element's properties? That's possible but you will need JavaScript

Comment: That's exactly right.